# problem using a keycloak UserStorageProvider SPI

Tags: java, keycloak

I have implemented a custom Keycloak UserStorageProvider SPI (following point 11 of official Doc: https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/index.html#_user-storage-spi) which does following:

1. Authenticate users (not previously existing on the local store) against an 
   external auth service.
2. Save the (successfully authenticated against our custom service) user into 
   the Keycloak local store.
3. After the users have been imported on keycloak's local store (after users
   successfully loged themselves in), the admins are then able to map roles
   to those users for resource authorization from keycloak's admin console.

The problem I'm running into is following: Step 1 and 2 work perfectly. And regarding step 3, I can log myself successfully with a user that was saved on the keycloak's local store (after finding it on the external UserProvider), BUT (an here lies the crux of the problem); as soon as I add any role to that imported user, then I can't log myself anymore into that account and the logs show that my custom UserStorageProvider isn't being used anymore from that point onwards when login for that user. Somehow attaching a role to that user makes him invisible to my custom UserStorageProvider (even if I delete the role/(s) again).

In the best case scenario I'm trying to achieve, I'd be able to "log in" with the user (saved locally after authenticated form external SPI), even after assigning roles to him.

Any feedback would be greatly appreciated!!

Thanks in advance for your suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the case somebody has this problem in the future, when you implement a provider SPI, you have 2 options as the doc mentions. Federated Store and importing users to the local Keycloak store. If you go with the importing/synching strategy, it is necessary to set federation link to the provider like this:

```
<UserModel instance>.setFederationLink(<ComponentModel id>);
```

If you don't do this, then Keycloak can't "remember" that those imported users should be handled by your provider SPI, and in general you won't have the expected behaviour out of your custom Provider SPI.

Comment: tony_008. Thanks for your tip.  I am trying to achieve the same and ran into problems on keyclaok_6.01.  What version of keycloak you are using.  Is there anyway you can share steps and key aspects of your code.
I am trying to implement authenticator similar to (https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/index.html#_auth_spi_walkthrough)

Comment: I'm using same version. You are doing a custom Authenticator SPI (section 8 of your Link); and I focused mainly on User Provider SPI (section  11 of your link), there are similiar elements to both but also differences. What type of specific problem do you have? can you create a question and share a link, because space here on the comments is very  limited.

Comment: Thanks @tony_008.  Posted my question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57477346/keycloak-custom-authenticator-spi-implementation)  after going thr' docs section 11, seems more right.  I will look into in more detail.  At the same time, if you could provide steps and guidance, it would be more helpfull.