# Keycloak User Storage SPI Implementation

Tags: java, keycloak, keycloak-services

I'm trying to implement a custom keycloack Authenticator SPI for authenticating against an external Datasource.  Spring boot Rest Service is also available, I can also use that.

Use case I am trying to solve is

> > User is presented keycloak login screen. Onsubmission User is validated against external Datasource.
> >
> > Retrieve some attributes from external datasource, map it to keycloak's id and access token.
> >
> > Also put in a condition of user restriction of same user logging in multiple times at the same time.
> >
> > I was thinking, it could be solved by retrieving user session information that's available in the keycloak datasource.  If i use external datasource, does keycloak still maintain session information?

I followed section 8.3 of the official guide (https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/index.html#_auth_spi_walkthrough), which is very similar to what I need.

Now i skipped and started as per section 11(https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/index.html#_user-storage-spi) seems more apt as well.

What I have done is started with implementing custom authenticator SPI thought it isn't the right way and now implemented UserStorageProvider.

```
/***
 * From UserLookupProvider
 */
public UserModel getUserById(String id, RealmModel realm) {
    System.out.println("ID: " + id + ":REALM:" + realm);
    StorageId storageId = new StorageId(id);
    /**
     * StorageId.getExternalId() method is invoked to obtain 
     * the username embeded in the id parameter
     */
    String username = storageId.getExternalId();
    System.out.println("Name:" + username);
    return getUserByUsername(username, realm);
}

/***
 * From UserLookupProvider
 * This method is invoked by the Keycloak login page when a user logs in
 */
public UserModel getUserByUsername(String username, RealmModel realm) {
    System.out.println("USERNAME: " + username + ":REALM:" + realm);
    UserModel userModel = loadedUsers.get(username);
    if (userModel == null) {
        String password = properties.getProperty(username);
        if (password != null) {
            userModel = createUserModel(realm, username);
            System.out.println("New UserModel:");
            System.out.println(userModel.toString());
            loadedUsers.put(username, userModel);
        }
    }
    return userModel;
}

protected UserModel createUserModel(RealmModel realm, String username) {
    return new AbstractUserAdapter(session, realm, model) {
        @Override
        public String getUsername() {
            return username;
        }
    };
}
```

Followed the doc(https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/index.html#packaging-and-deployment-2)

> The class files for our provider implementation should be placed in a jar. You also have to declare the provider factory class within the META-INF/services/org.keycloak.storage.UserStorageProviderFactory file.

Question here is: jar I created doesn't have services directory inside "META-INF" folder, do I need to create manually and add it?

> org.keycloak.examples.federation.properties.FilePropertiesStorageFactory
>   Once you create the jar you can deploy it using regular WildFly means: copy the jar into the deploy/ directory or using the JBoss CLI.

After creating jar using maven, copied jar to "keycloak-6.0.1\standalone\deployments" folder.  but i don't see my provider in the "User Federation list"[image: User Federation List]

Any suggestion/help would be greatly appreciated!!

Thanks in advance for your suggestions.

Comment: How did you package your jar? Did you have external dependencies? For me external dependencies are not becoming part of packaged jar. Even the maven shade plugin is not working as expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Ok you clarified you need a User Store Provider API. Great
- Now as for your 2nd "Problem/Challenge":

***Retrieve some attributes from external datasource, map it to keycloak's id and access token. Need to retrieve users unique id and add it as subject id in the jwt. That's the id, rest of the services can use to retrieve the id, when this token is passed to other services.***

For this, the best you can do is:

1. Add those user's unique data as users attributes (see them on the Admin console)
2. Create a "Client scope" on Keycloak, with a mapper for "user property" 
   to map those properties you'd like to add (from your user) to your Id-token and access-token. You also need to tie your client with your just created "client scope". This may sound a little bit confusing, but this video is great material and I bilieve it'll help you alot: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZxpY_zZ52kU  (arround min 6:30 you'll see how to add extra user info to your tokens)

also check this page out: https://jwt.io/ (when you paste there encoded tokens, you can see their contents), it is a great tool for developers.

When you advance in your solution I'll help with the unique session, or you post that as a different question, as that's a different problem.

Hope it helps.

Comment: @tony-008 For unique user session, I had posted a separate question(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57643410). Please let me know your thoughts/suggestion.

Comment: What would be your thoughts on Keycloak user session limit.  I have done it using Admin Rest api.  get admin token and use this endpoint(/auth/admin/realms/{realmId}/users/{userId}/sessions) to retrieve user session and validate it.  I feel there should be a better way

Comment: @amj .I haven't implemented this, but if I had to, my approach would be following: If you go to the admin realm/sessions section, you'll see the amount of open sessions per user client/user. It should be possible to programmatically query them. In your ProviderStore's custom validate() method, I'd add a check condition that the user in question needs to have 0 pre-existing sessions and not more (only if u are using password, if using a token then not because what u want is to avoid token creation if a user session already exist). By doing this token re-issuing should happen 1 by 1.

Answer (score 6):

Incase if anybody ran into issues like this:

UserStorage SPI wasn't displaying because of META-INF/services folder.  It's provided in the documentation but it isn't clear

In src/main/resources, create a folder structure META-INF/services

Create a file called org.keycloak.storage.UserStorageProviderFactory (the whole thing is the filename) in META-INF/services directory. Its contents is the fully qualified class name of your SPI:
com.test.UserSpi

[image: deploy jar]

Comment: can you share the whole directory structure for all the files. Also trying to create a UserStorage SPI.

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/java-keycloak-custom-user-providers For someone coming here to look for complete folder structure and implementation.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure what do you need. Lets start by differentiating Authentication SPI (federated identity check) vs User Provider SPI (federated users). The first one (section 8 of the doc - is more about focusing on authenticating users against an external service - similar to facebook, or google). Federated user store is more like you have your own users in a legacy system with their legacy "roles structure", and you basically want to manage them via keycloak (either by importing them, or by querying the via some API - this would be section 11 of that documentation). So please decide what is indeed what you need.

2nd, you mention following:

```
>  User is presented keycloak login screen. Onsubmission User is
> validated against external Datasource.
> 
> Retrieve some attributes from external datasource, map it to
> keycloak's id and access token.
> 
> Also put in a condition of user restriction of same user logging in
> multiple times at the same time.
> 
> I was thinking, it could be solved by retrieving user session
> information that's available in the keycloak datasource. If i use
> external datasource, does keycloak still maintain session information?
```

What do you mean by: ***Retrieve some attributes from external datasource, map it to keycloak's id and access token.*** ? Usually you only retrieve user core information, plus maybe roles and other custom attributes (not session information). Keycloak itself as an Authorization Server based on openIDConnect, will generate acces tokens which already contains information about what protected resource can by accessed by whom, so you dont really need to import any session from somewhere else, or concern yourself with the generation of said tokens.

regarding:  ***Also put in a condition of user restriction of same user logging in
 multiple times at the same time.*** what exactly are you trying to accomplish (or avoid?) when you log the 1st time your client receives a Bearer token valid for X amount of time, within that time you wont need to log yourself again, until the token expires or is roveked; again something your Auth server takes care of, not something you implement. Is there something more specific you want?

***I was thinking, it could be solved by retrieving user session information that's available in the keycloak datasource. If i use external datasource, does keycloak still maintain session information?*** This doesn't sound right, what session data do you refer to? or you need access to? your userdata, scopes, roles, etc can be accessed via KEycloak Rest API (https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/6.0/rest-api/index.html#_overview). Your external datasource is for user related core data (not external sessions), why do you think you need to import an external session?

Comment: Thanks @tony_008 for your comments.  I am gonna post multiple comments to answer your question.  I apologize for that, its because of character restrictions

Comment: I started with Custom Authenticator for authenticating against an external datasource.  As you pointed out earlier it's not meant for it.

Now, I started implementing User Provider SPI. Federated user store is what I need.  It works now, with some glitches.

Comment: _Retrieve some attributes from external datasource, map it to keycloak's id and access token._

Need to retrieve users unique id and add it as subject id in the jwt.  That's the id, rest of the services can use to retrieve the id, when this token is passed to other services.

Comment: _map it to keycloak's id and access token._ 
I was referring to keycloak's openId connect id token

Comment: _Also put in a condition of user restriction of same user logging in.  multiple times at the same time._

What I need to address here is, I need to prevent the same user logging in from multiple systems at the same time.  So, I was thinking best way is to validate them at the sigin, with stored session information.    If there is any better way to validate and prevent, please give suggestion/comment.

Comment: Hi, do u have a question for this (like a unique question without space constraints)?